# A question about nuclear C*-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

**Definition 2.3.1.** A C*-algebra $A$ is nuclear if the identity map $id_{A}: A\rightarrow A$ is nuclear.

**Definition 2.3.2.** A C*-algebra $A$ is exact if there exists a faithful representation $\pi:A \rightarrow B(H)$ such that $\pi$ is nuclear.

There is quotation below:

Let $\pi: A\rightarrow B(H)$ be a faithful representation, then ,

**(1). $A$ is nuclear if and only if $\pi$ is nuclear when regarded as taking values in $\pi(A)$.**

**(2). While $A$ is exact if and only if $\pi$ is nuclear when regarded as taking values in $B(H)$.**

My question is **how to explain regarding as taking values in $\pi(A)$ and $B(H)$ above, do they make any difference in estimating nuclearness and exactness?**

**Proof.** (1). "only if" Since $A$ is nuclear, then we have c.c.p. $\bar{\phi}_{n}: A \rightarrow M_{k(n)(C)}$ and $\bar{\psi}_{n}: M_{k(n)}(C)\rightarrow A$ such that $\bar{\psi}_{n} \circ \bar{\phi}_{n} \rightarrow I_{A}$ in point-norm topology. Then, we consider $\phi_{n}=\bar{\phi}_{n}$ and $\psi_{n}=\pi \circ \bar{\psi}_{n}$, we can check $\psi \circ \phi_{n} \rightarrow \pi$ in point-norm topology.

"if " Since $\pi$ is nuclear (and we take values in $\pi(A)$), we have  c.c.p. $\bar{\phi}_{n}: A \rightarrow M_{k(n)(C)}$ and $\bar{\psi}_{n}: M_{k(n)}(C)\rightarrow \pi(A)$ such that $\bar{\psi}_{n} \circ \bar{\phi}_{n} \rightarrow \pi$ in point-norm topology. Then we consider $\phi_{n}=\bar{\phi}_{n}$ and $\psi_{n}=\pi^{-1} \circ \bar{\psi}_{n}$, we can check $\psi \circ \phi_{n} \rightarrow I_{A}$ in point-norm topology.

(**Because of utilizing the invertibility of $\pi$, we need to consider the value in $\pi(A)$, right?**)

(2). "if" is clear from the definition. **But how to verify the "only if"? Could you give me some hints?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between nuclearity and exactness is that in the range of the maps $\psi_n$: when $\psi_n:M_{k(n)}(\mathbb C)\to \pi(A)$, the algebra is nuclear. When the range of $\psi_n$ is allowed to be bigger than $\pi(A)$, then $A$ is exact.

Comment: Yeah, and I edited my question. And I have two questions: 1. I give a brief proof of (1), is there anything wrong in my proof? 2. how to verify the "only if" in (2) above?

Comment: Your proof of 1 is correct.  There is nothing to prove in 2, it is exactly the definition.

Comment: But if $A$ is exact, there exists a faithful $\pi_{1}: A \rightarrow B(H_{1})$ such that $\pi_{1}$ is nuclear. I suppose this representation $\pi_{1}$ is different from the $\pi$ in the question above.

Comment: You are right.  But you just compose the second map in the nuclear decomposition of $\pi_1$ with $\pi\circ\pi_1^{-1}$ to get a nuclear decomposition for $\pi$.

Comment: I think $\pi_{1}$ may not be invertible because its range is $B(H_{1})$, not $\pi_{1}(A)$.

Comment: You are right. What you do is you extend $\pi\circ\pi_1^{-1}:\pi_1(A)\to\pi( A)$ to a cp map $\rho:B(H_1)\to B(H)$. Then you replace $\psi_n$ with $\rho\circ\psi_n$.

Comment: And do you use Arveson's Extension Theorem to extend the $\pi \circ \pi_{1}^{-1}$ tp $\rho$?

Comment: Yes indeed. ${ }$

Comment: You are welcome!